# In which file the custom properties information gets stored in WAS?

Tags: java, websphere

I have entered some wrong properties in the custom properties because of which my Administration Console is not coming up. So i am not able to re configure it. please if any of you know where this information gets stored, i can change it and restart my applicaiton.

need help.
thanks.

Comment: This is a server configuration issue, so I voted to close and send it to serverfault.

Comment: What errors do you see?  In particular, in startServer.log, SystemOut.log, SystemErr.log, native_stdout.log, and native_stderr.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably in the server profile's `server.xml`.